# Calculate average across replications

Tags: r, mean

I have data looking like:

```
Sample  Replication Days
1   1   10
1   1   14
1   1   13
2   1   NA
2   1   5
2   1   18
1   2   16
1   2   NA
1   2   18
2   2   15
2   2   7
2   2   12
```

I want to add a column for the average values of Samples across the replications. I want to keep replication as a factor to see if there is any effect because of replication. For example, an average of Sample 1 for replication 1 and an average of Sample 1 for replication 2 separately. Then I want to use that column for ANOVA using:

```
sample_aov <- aov(Sample~Days, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I tried using aggregate but I think I am making a mistake. I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, not a picture of it, which we can't run code on

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question, @camille!

Comment: So what's wrong with your `aov` results? And if you tried calling `aggregate` but made a mistake, what is it? Right now it's unclear what the question is, but there are a lot of posts already on calculating summary stats like mean by group

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`, you can process your dataframe as this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(Sample = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3),rep(1,3), rep(2,3)),
                Replication = c(rep(1,6), rep(2,6)),
                Days = c(10,14,13,NA,5,18,16,NA,18,15,7,12))

df <- df %>% group_by(Sample, Replication) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Days, na.rm = TRUE))
```

And you get the following dataframe:

```r
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Sample [2]
  Sample Replication  Mean
   <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
1      1           1  12.3
2      1           2  17  
3      2           1  11.5
4      2           2  11.3
```

Now you can perform `anova` test on this dataframe by doing:

```
> aov(Mean ~ Sample, data = d)
Call:
   aov(formula = Mean ~ Sample, data = d)

Terms:
                  Sample Residuals
Sum of Squares  10.56250  10.90278
Deg. of Freedom        1         2

Residual standard error: 2.334821
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

As you only have two groups to compare, a `t-test` is more appropriate:

```r
> t.test(Mean ~ Sample, data = df)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Mean by Sample
t = 1.392, df = 1.0026, p-value = 0.3962
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -26.23892  32.73892
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       14.66667        11.41667
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you, @dc37! Yes, this is similar to what I am looking for. But I have a question, I have shown to a few lines for my dataset. I have 100 samples over two replications. To make a data frame, do I need to enter all values manually as you did for df?

Comment: Thank you, So now I have the data imported but after running df <- df %>% group_by(Sample, Replication) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Days, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% mutate(AOV = ). I get an error: Error: object '' not found

Comment: So sorry, I forget to remove the last part of my code (`mutate(AOV = )` when editing my answer. Try without this part, it should work now.

Comment: It ran now but gave all 'NA' for the mean column.

Comment: Does your `Days` columns is in a numerical format ? (check it with `str(df)`)

Comment: You are right, Days was a factor earlier. So it made a column for the mean. But I compared it with the manually calculated numbers and these are different. Basically, there are 134 samples with 4 values for each but df says # A tibble: 135 x 3

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, when converting, it will assign he order levels as numerical values. I get this kind of errors quite frequently :(. Maybe you can try to first transform as a vector and then as numerical. `df$Days = as.vector(df$Days)` and then `df$Days = as.numeric(df$Days)`

Comment: Thank you! After ANOVA, I calculated, `lsmeans(anova, ~Sample)`. Then I created means and SE, `Design<-lsmeans(anova, ~Sample)`
`Design<-summary(anova)` Then I plotted it, `p<- ggplot(Design,aes(x=Sample,y=lsmean))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black", fill="grey", width = 1) + geom_errorbar(aes(x=Line, ymin = lsmean-SE, ymax = lsmean+SE), width = 0.25, color = "black") +  (limits = c(0, 40)) 
But it says data should be dataframe. I want to plot it using confidence interval as error bars. Can you help.

Comment: Glad that it works and you were able to continue your analysis ! Good luck

Comment: Yes, But I had an issue in ggplot that I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: The output of `summary(anova)` is a list, so you can plot it as it is with `ggplot`. You should ask a new question for that because we are going out of focus of your first question and need much more detailed information that what can be contain in comments

Answer (score 1):

Let us use your original suggestion to use `aggregate`. We will call your `data.frame` `df`. Noting that your grouping variables are `sample` and `repl` use:

```
> val <- aggregate(.~sample+repl, df, FUN=mean)
> val
  sample   repl          days
       1      1      12.33333
       2      1      11.50000
       1      2      17.00000
       2      2      11.33333
```

You are ready to perform your anova.